# Jacobson radical and idempotent element e

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I've been asked to solve the following question:

Given that $e$ is a non-zero idempotent element of a unital ring $R$, show that:

$rad_{J}(eRe) = (eRe)\cap rad_{J}R = e(rad_{J}R)e$.

The strategy I was told to use was by inclusion - show that they're subsets of each other and to also use the fact that $1 - ra$ is invertible for all $r\in R$.

Can anyone give me some steps in the right direction?

Comment: Why on Earth (and beneath) do you need $e$ nonzero?....

Comment: Actually, this is Theorem (21.10) in T. Y. Lam's *A First Course in Noncommutative Rings*, 1991. See https://books.google.com/books?id=2PwGCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA321&lpg=PA321&dq=jacobson+radical+of+ere&source=bl&ots=Qimmb8A-2m&sig=67M7Luir3618Js9VLUCdYPkz3IY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi00JH_qL3QAhVpyoMKHaw8A9wQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=jacobson%20radical%20of%20ere&f=false .

Comment: Does the requirement of $e$ being nonzero mean the proofs have to be changed in any way?

Comment: Nope. It's clearly a useless requirement -- everything is obviously correct if $e=0$.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help.